# How to produce the same result of to_char() on the same DB instance, but from different sessions?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, to-char, nls-lang

I have a small utility function that calculates the day of week from a given date:

```
select to_number(to_char(to_date('20130330', 'YYYYMMDD'),'D')) from dual;
```

Executing this statement on the same database instance, but from two different machines it produces two different results!

**The question is**: how to modify the code in order to get the same result on two different PC but using the same database instance?

## Details

**The result is 6** when I start a session from my pc with these nls_session parameters:

```
select * from nls_session_parameters;

NLS_LANGUAGE    HUNGARIAN
NLS_TERRITORY   HUNGARY
NLS_CURRENCY    Ft
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    HUNGARY
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  , 
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT RR-MON-DD
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   HUNGARIAN
NLS_SORT    HUNGARIAN
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    RR-MON-DD HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT RR-MON-DD HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   Ft
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

**The same database instance gives different result: 7** by starting a session from a different pc which has these session paramters:

```
PARAMETER    VALUE
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY    AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS    .,
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT    HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT    HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY    $
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP    FALSE
```

For me the correct result is 7, but it must be provided on my PC. I've tried the following without success:

- Altered the NLS_LANGUAGE to AMERICAN
- Used to_char() with the optional nls_language parameter

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operative setting for day of week is [`NLS_TERRITORY`](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2205756).

Answer (score 2):

If you can issue an `alter session` then NLS_TERRITORY is probably the way to go, as @JoachimIsaksson says. But if you can't, then unfortunately [`TO_CHAR()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#sthref1650) doesn't support modifying it on the fly via its optional `nlsparms` argument.

You could brute-force it as a last resort, e.g. in a Hungarian session:

```
alter session set nls_language = 'HUNGARIAN';

select to_char(to_date('20130330', 'YYYYMMDD'), 'DY') as hungarian,
    to_char(to_date('20130330', 'YYYYMMDD'),
        'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') as american
from dual;

HUN AME
--- ---
SZO SAT

select case to_char(to_date('20130330', 'YYYYMMDD'),
    'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')
        when 'SUN' then 1 when 'MON' then 2 when 'TUE' then 3
        when 'WED' then 4 when 'THU' then 5 when 'FRI' then 6
        when 'SAT' then 7
    end as american
from dual;

  AMERICAN
----------
         7
```

... which is ugly but avoids any side-effects from changing the session. And you could turn it into a function if this is going to be an issue in more than one place, of course.

Answer (score 0):

For the International convention, just use trunc(date)-trunc(date,'IW')+1
If you prefer US convention, it is trunc(date+1)-trunc(date+1,'IW')+1.